# How do I make the AppDelegate a NSWindowDelegate?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm finally trying out storyboards on OSX and have become confused by the structure of a generated project.  *Basically, I'd like to know how `windowWillReturnUndoManager` is supposed to work as part of the application delegate.*

1. I create a Cocoa application with Storyboards, Core Data, and no
   documents.
2. The generated AppDelegate contains an implementation of `-
   (NSUndoManager *)windowWillReturnUndoManager:(NSWindow *)window`.
3. The AppDelegate is not defined as a `NSWindowDelegate`, however.
4. The above method is never called.

Trying to set the AppDelegate as the window delegate gives me some problems.

1. The Application Scene has the AppDelegate object and the Window
   Controller Scene has the window, so IB connections don't work.
2. `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` is called before the application's mainWindow is available.

I can make it work by defining a `mainWindow` ivar and using code like...

```
- (void)applicationDidUpdate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    if (!mainWindow) {
        NSWindow *appWindow = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow];
        if (appWindow) {
            mainWindow = appWindow;
            [mainWindow setDelegate:self];
        }
    }
}
```

...and it sets the delegate the **fourth** time it's called.  To me, that seems like a ridiculous hack.

What's the expected strategy here?

Comment: Why does it need to be in the app delegate?  Isn't that class already performing a distinct role?

Comment: Excellent questions, but since that's where Apple's application template stuffed it, I'm assuming there's an intended way to make it work.  Subclassing NSWindowController sounds like a better "real world" approach, however I hate the feeling that I'm missing something.

Comment: Well it depends on what sort of application you are writing but subclassing `NSWindowController` would be what I would do.  If it's a small app then keep a reference to this subclass as an instance variable of the app delegate.